# group line segments into minimum set of polyline

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

Given a list of line segments I need to construct a list of polyline while keeping the number of polylines minimum.

The polylines must not visit the same edge more than once.

For example if I was given the 4 edges of a rectangle then one polyline would be sufficient.
If I was given the 6 edges of a rectangle with a cross in the middle then I would need two polyline to cover it.

This problem looks very similar to travelling sales man problem so I am not sure if a solution exists. I can live with a sub optimal solution in that case.

Edit:
Performance is more important than precision for us so ideally we would want to group the ones that almost join (1-2 pixels away from joining) each other into one polyline

Examples:

1. input for a square:
   L(0, 0) - (0, 1), L(0, 1) - (1, 1), L(1, 1) - (1, 0), L(1, 0) - (0, 0)
   Expected output: Polyline (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), Close
2. input for a square with X:
   L(0, 0) - (0, 1), L(0, 1) - (1, 1), L(1, 1) - (1, 0), L(1, 0) - (0, 0), L(0, 0) - (1, 1), L(1, 0) - (0, 1)
   One possible output: Polyline1 (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0), (1, 1)   Polyline2 (1, 0), (0, 1)
3. input for lines close to each other:
   L(0, 0) - (1, 0), L(2, 0) - (3, 0)
   Ideal output: Polyline (0, 0), (3, 0)

Comment: and why is this downvoted?

Comment: Whoever downvoted probably believes that the only acceptable type of question here is the one where you provide the code that doesn't work.

Comment: Could you provide an example input and expected output? If input points are constrained to integers must output points also be constrained? Can output point be some that does not exist in input?

Comment: @Dialecticus input points are all integers. Performance is more important than precision for us so ideally we would want to group the ones that almost join (1-2 pixels away from joining) each other into one polyline

Comment: Give an input example with lines that are 2 pixels away, and desired output. This is how Stack Overflow works, we need an example.

Comment: @Dialecticus hopefully the examples are clear enough

Comment: You can solve this in polynomial time: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_inspection_problem.  Actually that problem is a harder problem since you don't care about minimising "repeating edges"; it may be that algorithms for finding Eulerian paths and circuits are all you need.  To group nearby points, I would suggest first rounding all x and y co-ordinates to the nearest multiple of, e.g., 5.

Comment: If you connect all the neighboring points with a special kind of "non-required" edges, then there is a variant called "rural postman problem".